# Trying to create a Countdown in react.js (day : hours : minutes : seconds) with UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

As the title says, im trying to create a countdown that starts at

`4 days : 23 hours : 59 minutes : 59 seconds` , and counts down to `0 days: 0 hours : 0 minutes : 0 seconds`

So far I have the following

```
import * as React from "react";

const Countdown = (props) => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(2);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = React.useState(2);
  const [hours, setHours] = React.useState(2);
  const [days, setDays] = React.useState(4);
  const [timeDone, setDone] = React.useState(false);
 //SECONDS

  //seconds 60 -> 0
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const secondsCounter =
      seconds > 0 && setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondsCounter);
  }, [seconds]);

  //seconds == 60 (when seconds == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setSeconds(2);
  }, [seconds == 0 && !timeDone ]);

//MINUTES

  //Minutes 60 -> 0  (when seconds == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setMinutes(minutes-1)
  }, [seconds == 0]);

  //Minutes == 60 (when minutes == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setMinutes(2);
  }, [minutes == 0 && !timeDone]);

//HOURS

  //hours 24 => 0 (when minutes == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setHours(hours - 1);
  }, [minutes == 0]);

  //hours == 23 (when hours == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setHours(2);
  }, [hours == 0 && !timeDone]);

//DAYS
  //days 5 => 0 (when hours == 0)
  React.useEffect(() => {
      return () => setDays(days-1);
  }, [hours == 0 && !timeDone])

//DONE

  React.useEffect(() => {
      return () => setDone(true)
  }, [days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0])


  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        countdown: {days} : {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Countdown;
```

But it doesnt work as I expect, + every time that the minutes go down they go down by 2 minutes, same happens with hours, seems that useEffect is executed 2 times, and I dont understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could be simplified much further into something like this.
The value you render is dependent only on the current time, everything else is just derivation of `this` time with respect to your `timeLeft`

```
function calculateTimeLeft() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const difference = +new Date(`${year}-10-1`) - +new Date();
  let timeLeft = {};

  if (difference > 0) {
    timeLeft = {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
    };
  }

  return timeLeft;
}

export default function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });

  const timerComponents = Object.keys(timeLeft).map(interval => {
    if (!timeLeft[interval]) {
      return;
    }

    return (
       <span>
        {timeLeft[interval]} {interval}{" "}
      </span>
    )
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <span>Time's up!</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could see the working example here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t86icp

Comment: I think it should be setInterval instead of setTimeout, otherwise, setTimeLeft will not be executed every second.

Comment: You could see `useEffect` being triggered every state update with `setTimeout`. So, this will work as well. You could check the demo.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Prateek!

Answer (score 1):

All your useEffects are actually running 2 times

Initially, your (seconds == 0) is false, it becomes true when seconds become 0, useEffect ran once then and you were setting it to 59 and now (seconds == 0) is false again, useEffect is run again. Same thing is happening for minutes, hours, so on. useEffect is run both when they become 0 and 59. Instead what you should do is set the value to 59 only when the bool cond is true